# Is it better to use std::string or single char when possible?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it better to use `std::string` or single `char` when possible?

In my class I want to store certain characters. I have `CsvReader`
class, and I want to store `columnDelimiter` character. I wonder,
is it better to have it as `char`, or just use `std::string`?
In terms of usage I suppose `std::string` is far better, but I wonder
maybe there will be major performance differences?

Comment: It depends. What are your delimiters? What performance cost have you encountered?

Comment: If you needed to store someone's age, what would you use? An integer, or an std::vector<int> which happens to always have size 1, just to take advantage of the lots of things you can do with an std::vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If your delimiter is constrained to be a single character, use a `char`.
- If your delimiter may be a string, use a `std::string`.

Seems fairly self-explanatory. Refer to the requirements of the project, and the constraints of the feature that follow from those requirements.

Personally it seems to me that a CSV field delimiter will always be a single character, in which case `std::string` is not only misleading, but pointlessly heavy.

> In terms of usage I suppose std::string is far better

I have largely ignored this claim as you did not provide any rationale, but let me just say that I reject the hypothetical premise of the claim.

> I wonder maybe there will be major performance differences?

Absolutely! A string consists of a dynamically-allocated block of characters; this is entirely more heavy than a single byte in memory. Notwithstanding the small-string-optimisation that your implementation may perform, it's simply *pointless* to add all this weight when all you wish to represent is a single character. A single character *is* a `char`, so use a `char` in such a case.

Comment: Well even though it is a char, it will be nice to have it as std::string :)

Comment: @user3111311: Why's that?

Comment: Well you can do many operations with a string, for the char you will have to convert all the time to std::string.

Comment: @user3111311: For example?

Comment: You are right I see now, no need for the extra weight of string.

Answer (score 1):

A character is a character. A string is a string; conceptually, a set of N characters, where N is any natural number.

If your design requires a character, use `char`. If it requires a string, use `string`.

In both cases you may have multilanguage issues (what happens if the characteer is 青? what happens if the string is 青い?), but these are totally independent of your choice of whether you need a character or a set of N characters, i.e. a string.

Comment: I think the OP's question stems from the fact that `N` can be `1`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit Yes. But if N is always 1, then his _actual_ requirement is a character, not a string.